# How to enable user interaction of a view that is an index of a tab bar controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am currently using a tab bar controller with 3 tabs, which I will refer to as tab 0, 1 and 2. Lets say a user is currently seeing the view controller that is in index 0 in the tab bar controller. When a user taps a button on this view, two things happen
1. a task is initiated, which is handled by a separate controller class
2. i call `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1` to move the UI over to the view controller that is in index 1 of my tab bar.

At this time, right after the user taps the button from the previous view, I have disabled the user interaction of the current view (index 1) within the tab bar controller, by putting it in `viewWillAppear()`.

THEN, after a few seconds, the task that was initiated, finishes and, via delegation, I receive a callback on the viewController that is currently in view(index 1 in my tab bar). At this point when the callback is received, I would like to enable user interaction for the current view.

here is my code...

```
    func updateUIOnTaskCompletion(){

      self.loadView()
      self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

      //I have also tried the following with no success
      //      self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController?.loadView()
      //      self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController?.loadView()

      //      self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController!.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
      //      self.tabBarController?.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

}
```

the reason i call `loadView()` is because without calling this, the app crashes due to `found nil while unwrapping an optional...`. Since view is an optional, calling `loadView()` prevents the value from being nil and thus the app doesn't crash. However, the user interaction still never gets enabled. I have also tried without success the code that I have commented out above.Any suggestions would be super appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: I see in apple docs that one should never call `loadView()`, so there must be a better way than what I am doing, however it is unbeknownst to me!

EDIT: FYI, when I use `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1`, to move the UI to the view within index 1, i am able to disable the user interaction for this view by putting `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false` within the `viewWillAppear()` method. However, when I receive my delegate callback on this view controller just a few moments later, calling `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true` does not work, nor do any of the methods I have tried as seen above.

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to enable and disable a tab in a tab bar as needed?

Comment: no sorry about the confusion, I want enable interaction for the view that is in the viewController that is within my tab bar's index 1. I have disabled the interaction successfully in viewWillAppear. But then when I receive the callback I want to re-enable interaction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of turning off user interaction at the view level, turn it off at the *application* level with UIApplication `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` and `endIgnoringInteractionEvents`.

Comment: YOU ARE MY OBI-WAN!!! Struggling with this seemingly trivial issue for hours, your answers have saved my butt more times than you know, thanks again!!!